# Compare two (non-STL) maps for equality

Tags: c++, algorithm, set, equality

A 3rd-party library we're using is essentially a map/dictionary. It doesn't provide any way of equality testing two objects against each other and we need this.

More specifically, two maps S1 & S2 are considered equal if:

1. Every key in S1 is a key in S2
2. Every key in S2 is a key in S1
3. For every key K in S1, S1[K] == S2[K]

Note, the internal ordering in each map is irrelevant and may not be relied on, so direct comparison of internal structure/members isn't possible. We do have ways to compare keys and values for equality.

What is the neatest algorithm to do this? Pseudo C++ is just fine since the exact API on the set class is close enough to std::map I can translate.

Comment: can you iterate through the set in a way the guarantees a lexographical order of keys?

Comment: See edit - no. No access to internal structure is provided by the API.

Comment: Constructing a `std::set` copies from the contents so that you can then write `if (s1 == s2)`? If perf is lacking you can switch to manual mode.

Comment: what do you mean with `S1[K]`? is `S1` actually a `map` (i.e. storing  a key-value pair)?

Comment: @John Does the class provide iterators? What's its `value_type`? Is it ordered?

Comment: Sorry all, brain-fart... it's map not set... dictionary was the right term.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compare sizes

- if the sizes are equal

  - iterate the keys in the first set and for each key:

    - check that the key exists in the second set
    - check that the elements for the key are equal
- If at least one element is not equal, one key in first set does not exist in the second or the sizes are not equal, the sets are unequal.

Comment: how are you going to compare elements from different sets for equality? a set only compares elements for equivalence (e.g. using `<`)

Comment: @TemplateRex, if John asked that "For every key K in S1, S1[K] == S2[K]", I am going to assume that both getting a value from the set by key, and comparing values for equality, are supported by his public interfaces. I am unsure what you are asking ("a set only compares elements for equivalence" - are you referring to `std::set`s?)

Comment: If the sets are usually equal, i.e. being different is the exception, then it may be more efficient to check the sizes of the sets *after* iterating the keys in the first set.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: at least on `std::set`, getting `size()` "should have constant complexity" (23.1.5 of the c++03 standard)

Comment: @arne: That only tells you the complexity, not the runtime speed. ;-)

Comment: @TemplateRex: utnamistim is right. For Key K I want to check the values stored in both are equal/equivalent.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe While you're correct from a theoretical point of view, one lookup of the size will probably be negligible in comparison to a bunch of key accesses and comparisons.

Comment: @arne: Definately, I'm just being pedantic, sorry. ;-)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: I know, and that's not necessarily a bad thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well this method is valid as long as the maximum value stored in the set is known correctly. Take an array of size of `maximum value+1` and initialize it to `0`. Then iterate through the first set and `increment` the array values at 'key' position by its corresponding `value`.

Now iterate through the second set and `decrement` the values in the array at the index `key` by its `value`.

At the end check if all the array values are `zero`. If not, then they are `unequal`, else they are `equal`.

Time Complexity: `O(N)`

Memory:`O(max_value)`

Comment: Your proposed algorithm only checks that the sets have the same keys, not the same values. It could also be optimized by comparing set sizes before any iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your map API has iterators (or indices), is ordered, contains no duplicates and also stores its key and mapped types as nested typedefs, you could implement the same semantics of `std::map::operator==` in `O(N)` time:

```
#include <functional> // less
#include <algorithm>  // includes

// O(N) complexity
template<class MyMap, class KeyCmp = std::less<typename MyMap::key_type, class TCmp = std::equal<typename MyMap::mapped_type> >
bool set_equality(MyMap const& lhs, MyMap const& rhs, KeyCmp keycmp, TCmp tcmp) 
{
    typedef typename MyMap::value_type Pair;

    return 
        lhs.size() == rhs.size() && 
        std::includes(
            lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), 
            rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), 
            [](Pair const& p1, Pair const& p2){
            return keycmp(p1.first, p2.first) && tcmp(p1.second, p2.second);
        })
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that one main question to answer is how expensive a single lookup in that dictionary structure is. If you have e.g. a hashmap's O(1), a comparison loop like what utnapistim suggests  would be O(n) * O(1) = O(n) in complexity. If the underlying dictionary is a std::map, you would have O(log n) lookups, making it O(n * log n) overall. If your dict was implemented on top of an unsorted array or list, you would have O(n) lookups making it overall O(n^2).

The reason I'm mentioning these is that you can also sort the two dictionaries and compare the results. Sorting them is O(n * log n), like for std::map, so without knowing the lookup complexity you can't decide whether sorting the sequence is more or less expensive.

There is another aspect I'd like to mention and that is the ordering of the dictionary. You say that you can't assume anything there but there is only one common structure that I'm aware of that doesn't provide a guarantee that equal content means equal order, an unsorted array or linked list. However, that performs badly as dictionary because lookup is O(n), so it is very unlikely that someone chose it as underlying container. Writing this, I wonder whether hashmaps give the guarantee if they have different bucket sizes and perhaps histories, I'm really not sure. Where I'm sure though is that the best algorithm depends on the lookup complexity of the dictionary, so I would try to find out more about this. Even measuring would be preferable to knowing nothing. A well-documented hack that relies on a certain behaviour for performance is IMHO acceptable.